# Typo3 DateTime setter issue

Tags: php, datetime, typo3, extbase

my appointment model has a value $created which is of the datatype DateTime. But for some reason i am not able to set the $created values.

I tried many formats, but it just won't set the value. It gets stuck when the function reaches the setCreated(). (All other values (ints, strings) are set successfully, just this \DateTime var not)

```
$appointment->setCreated('1439878630');  //Doesn't work
$appointment->setCreated(1439878630);    //Doesn't work  
$appointment->setCreated('1990-11-14T15:32:12+00:00'); //Doesn't work
$appointment->setCreated('1990-11-14 15:32:12'); //Doesn't work
```

my setter method:

```
 /**
 * Sets the created
 *
 * @param \DateTime $created
 * @return void
 */

public function setCreated(\DateTime $created) {
    $this->created = $created;
}
```

how can i set the $created value with a timestamp (or any other date-format)??
any help is appreciated!
tia for your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setCreated`-method needs a `DateTime` object, not a string. So give it one:

```
$appointment->setCreated(new \DateTime('<insert your date string here>'));
```

The list of accepted time strings can be found in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).

Comment: worked like a charm. you literally made my day Jost. Thx man!!!  p.s. which kind of datatype does the \DateTime initialization accept? Only date strings or can i just pass it a timestamp???

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this? It should be working...

```
$appointment->setCreated(new \DateTime('1990-11-14T15:32:12+00:00'));
```

Comment: Yes...I didn't see his answer. I am glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$appointment->setCreated('1990-11-14 15:32:12');
```

Comment: yes - same issue. tried multiple DateTime formats described in http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php but without success.

Comment: I always enjoy downvotes with no justification whatsoever...People could at least justify, so one can improve the answer.

Comment: i just made an upvote so your post is on 0. Well i also don't understand why people just downvote. as long as its not absolute clutter that shouldn't be done. And thanks for your support and effort!

Comment: @d4ny3l that wasn't needed, but thank you. When I added this suggestion you did not have that option on your question, but now you do. Maybe that is why someone downvoted...